# How to generate keystore for android application signing with 2048 bits keysize using Eclipse ADT wizard?

Tags: android, eclipse, code-signing, jar-signing

I want to create a keystore for my android application to signing my application in release mode. I followed the procedure which is given in [Android Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#setup).

In this document says that if we didn't provide keysize for generating keystore it take default size as 1024 bits, but in general they recommended 2048 bits.

By using command line we can create 2048 bits keysize keystore. But when using Eclipse ADT Wizard to creating keystore there is no option to give the keysize.

So, will the wizard will create 1024 bits keysize or 2048 bits keysize keystore? If wizard creates a 1024 bit keysize, how can I create 2048 bits keysize keystore using Eclipse ADT wizard?

Answer (score 1):

adt -certificate -cn SelfSign -ou QE -o "Topr" -c US 2048-RSA adt.p12 password

can produce 2048bit p12 file

Comment: You need to explain your answer. This is too short to be useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the wizard does generate by default a 1024 bit key. I got this information by exporting the keystore to a p12, loading it in firefox and viewing the certificate details -> certificate signature value.

To answer your question, I'm not sure that there is a way to specify with the ADT to get a 2048 bit key. It is probably hardcoded into the eclipse android plugin, so unless you want to locate that bit of source code and recompile, I would just use keytool. The command they use works and generates a 2048 bit key. You can then open eclipse and sign your apk with that shiny new key.